# ios run app in background forever using audio / voip modes

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, core-audio, avaudioplayer

**I Want To Run App In Background Forever Using Audio And VOIP Modes                       Does Apple Reject App To Upload To Appstore**

Comment: Yes , if they feel you are not using background modes for right purpose , they reject it

Comment: I think your app is not a VOIP app.

Answer (score 1):

**They will reject it if you are using the wrong mode or using this ability for other purposes** (means you are cheating the user). General rule is that if you specify some background mode user has to benefit from that (you are consuming more energy) if he doesn't then your app probably will be rejected. So I wouldn't recommend you using any hacks like playing silent voice to keep app running etc. **Keep the right mode with the right usage.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes , if they feel you are not using background modes for right purpose , they reject it

You can read here [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

> 2.16 `Multitasking Apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc.`

Hope this helps.